# Declined flag for new answer duplicating existing ones

Tags: discussion, flagging, low-quality-posts

I had a [flag](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58814/how-do-i-add-environment-variables/557640#557640) declined for this reason:

> This answer does not add anything constructive to existing answers. – muru 22 hours ago   declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

As I understand, late answers which don't add anything constructive are deleted, and this answer does not add anything (`gksudo gedit /etc/environment` is already present in the accepted answer). I used a moderator flag because a low-quality one was already declined. I believe I am right in flagging that answer. Do we no longer delete such answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes we do - and should - delete answers that are a mirror of existing ones.

In this case, the answer is actually an answer.  Its a step-by-step guide.  Important for a new person to understand.  Agreed, it may seemingly be superfluous to someone more confident with what the top answer has said in an abbreviated form.

The top answer - yes it conveys similar information.  But to my eyes, not in a user-friendly step-by-step guide.

Why has it got negative votes - probably because of the reference to "777".  There is no reason really why this answer could not just be tidied up by just removing this bit.

Alternatively - we can thank the OP - drop a comment.  Add the step-by-step guide into the top answer and then we can clean-up.

Comment: Ok, cleaning it up now.